# [FIRA_AppDelegate- messaging:didRefreshRegistrationToken:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance - firebase crash issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I found a new issue when I reinstalled the iOS app. Before reinstalling the app worked fine. Before reinstalling I updated cocoa sdk repo and it updated Firebase and FirebaseDatabase version from 3.15.0 to version 4.0.0.

Here is the crash log below:

> -[FIRA_AppDelegate-1495465837867 messaging:didRefreshRegistrationToken:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x174661b40 2017-05-22 23:10:58.550969+0800
>   moodfriends[1716:245390] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[FIRA_AppDelegate-1495465837867
>   messaging:didRefreshRegistrationToken:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x174661b40'

Comment: Can you share some piece of code where this issue is found?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just found the solution.

Changed

```
[FIRMessaging messaging].remoteMessageDelegate = self;
```

to

```
[FIRMessaging messaging].delegate = self;
```

It seems remoteMessageDelegate is deprecated with the version update and should FIRMessagingDelegate delegate functions.

Swift 3:

```
Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
```

Comment: that's what my answer was telling you.

Comment: didn't fix my issue.

Answer (score 6):

the crash occurred because either the class has no declaration of method messaging:didRefreshRegistrationToken:

or you didn't have set delegate for Firebase Message

Comment: Thanks .. This solved my issue. I think this should be a accepted Answer.

Comment: @vivek   ok . so  how to add that method messaging:didRefreshRegistrationToken: .. ? can you guide me through it ?

Comment: @Moxarth You will have more idea about this method here https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasemessaging/api/reference/Protocols/FIRMessagingDelegate

Comment: @vivek thanks . i have figured out my issue after referring firebase documents . and that was exactly what you have mentioned . i had no declaration of method messaging:didRefreshRegistrationToken: . i implemented it and issue solved .